# Python 用途に応じてログファイルを分けて出力したい。

Tags: python, python3, logging

用途別（通信、ユーザー操作、その他など）にログファイルを分けて出力したいのですが、
以下のコードでは、2つのログファイルに同じ出力となります。
※本来のコードから切り貼りしており、一部なんでこんな書き方？となっているとは思いますが、ご容赦ください。

意図するところでは、    
alog.debug("なんでこうなるのか？")->app.logのみに出力したい。
ulog.debug("わかりません。")->user.logのみに出力したい。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃれば、ご教示をお願いします。

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import logging.handlers

class _writeLog():
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def debug(self,log_text,*args,**kwargs):
        ret = self.logger.debug(log_text,*args,**kwargs)
        return ret

    def info(self,log_text,*args,**kwargs):
        ret = self.logger.info(log_text,*args,**kwargs)
        return ret

    def warning(self,log_text,*args,**kwargs):
        ret = self.logger.warning(log_text,*args,**kwargs)
        return ret

    def error(self,log_text,*args,**kwargs):
        ret = self.logger.error(log_text,*args,**kwargs)
        return ret

    def critical(self,log_text,*args,**kwargs):
        ret = self.logger.critical(log_text,*args,**kwargs)
        return ret

    def notset(self,log_text,*args,**kwargs):
        ret = self.logger.debug(log_text,*args,**kwargs)
        return ret

def write_log():
    _Log = dict()

    LOGS_FORMAT = (
        "%(asctime)s "
        "%(name)s "
        "%(process)06d "
        "%(thread)06d "
        "%(levelname)8s "
        "%(message)s"
        )

    path = [
        'app',
        'user'
        ]
    for i in range(2):
        hLog = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(path[i]+'.log',backupCount=2,maxBytes=1*1024*1024)
        hLog.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(LOGS_FORMAT))
        hLog.setLevel('DEBUG')
        _Log.setdefault(path[i],hLog)

    app_handler = _Log['app']
    user_handler = _Log['user']

    log_header = __name__

    app_logger = logging.getLogger(log_header)
    user_logger = logging.getLogger(log_header)

    app_logger.setLevel('DEBUG')
    app_logger.addHandler(app_handler)

    alog = _writeLog(app_logger)

    user_logger.setLevel('DEBUG')
    user_logger.addHandler(user_handler)

    ulog = _writeLog(user_logger)

    alog.debug("なんでこうなるのか？")
    ulog.debug("わかりません。")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_log()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logging.getLogger` によって取得されるロガーオブジェクトは、同一 name に対しては、同じインスタンスが返されるからです。なので、 addHander は同じ、 `__main__` の名前を持った logger に対して実行されています。 (スクリプトとして実行したならば)

```
print(repl(user_logger is app_logger))
# => True
```

例えばこうすると、やりたいことがひとまずはできると思います。

```
app_logger = logging.getLogger(f"{__name__}.app")
user_logger = logging.getLogger(f"{__name__}.user")

# -> 別々の logger になるので、それぞれ別々の handler を追加してもまざらない。
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
理解不足でした。参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: @TakahiroFunahashi この回答で問題が解決した場合、チェックマークをクリックしてこの回答を「承認」していただけますか？システム的に、問題が解決済であることを示すことができます。